# why was `ResizeObserver` introduced to listen to resize changes and not a simpler Element.prototype.addEventListener('resize', callback)

Tags: javascript, dom, resize, addeventlistener, window-resize

I'm a bit surprised that in order to listen to changes on elements dimensions (not window Object) we have to use a new interface called `ResizeObserver`. While it seems to do the job pretty well; it seems a bit of a departure from other element related events that can be consumed by just adding a listener.

Take for example adding an event listener to listen for the mouseover event

```
document.querySelector('#ele').addEventListener('mouseover', callback);
```

Why not simply add a new listener to the resize event on the elements?

```
document.querySelector('#ele').addEventListener('resize', callback);
```

Is it to avoid conflicts with the window `resize` event? If so, why not just call it differently

```
document.querySelector('#ele').addEventListener('elementResize', callback);
```

I'm aware it is easy to create a helper method to simplify the usage of the `ResizeObserver`. Something like that can be as simple to use as the original `addEventListener` approach

```
export const getResizeObserver = ( ele, onResize ) => {
  let obs;

  const observerInterface = {
    stop: () => { obs.unobserve( ele ); obs.disconnect() },
  };

  obs = new ResizeObserver( entries => {
    for ( const entry of entries ) {
      onResize && onResize( entry.contentRect );
    }
  } );

  obs.observe( ele );

  return observerInterface;
};

// usage to add the listener
const obs = getResizeObserver(document.querySelector('#ele'), callback);
// later to remove the listener
obs.stop();
```

In any case, **Is there any reason, besides just api preferences and the fact that several elements can share the observer instance, that makes the `ResizeObserver` approach better than the `addEventListener` approach?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was [proposed](https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/issues/43) (and the issue is still open), but Chrome decided to ship this using the Observer model, seemingly mostly because it was 10x faster than an implementation based on events https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/z6ienONUb5A

Now why *that’s* true, I don’t know.

Answer (score 10):

There is a discussion [in this PR](https://github.com/w3ctag/design-principles/issues/78) in which the W3C technical architecture group tries to define when to use the Observer pattern over the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). The output of this discussion is documented [here](https://w3ctag.github.io/design-principles/#events-vs-observers), and I'm quoting the first statement:

> In general, use EventTarget and notification Events, rather than an
> Observer pattern, unless an EventTarget can’t work well for your
> feature.

The advantages of using an Observer pattern over [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) are as follows:

> 1. Instances can be customized at observation time or at creation time. The constructor for an Observer, or its `observe()` method, can take options allowing authors to customize what is observed for each callback. This isn’t possible with `addEventListener()`.
> 2. It’s easy to stop listening on multiple callbacks using the `disconnect()` or `unobserve()` method on the Observer object.
> 3. You have the option to provide a method like `takeRecords()`, which immediately fetches the relevant data instead of waiting for an event to fire.
> 4. Because Observers are single-purpose, you don’t need to specify an event type.

Talking specifically about the `ResizeObserver`, **in my opinion**:

- The 2nd and 4th points aren't too relevant. It doesn't add or take anything crucial, and I think that the `resize` event would be a much better match here.
- It still doesn't implement the `takeRecords()` method, so the 3d point irrelevant

It leaves us with the ability to customize it at the creation and observation time and allows changing these customization APIs later on without changing the [Event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event) model.

Also, there are possible performance issues or [an unavoidable recursion](https://w3ctag.github.io/design-principles/#guard-against-recursion), but I didn't find any measurements or explanations regarding them.